# Error creando función desde psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Necesito crear funciones para postgresql desde python, pero al ejecutar el script de creación desde psycopg2 lo único que consigo es un error.

**Script de creación de la función**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
  RETURNS numeric AS $BODY$ 
DECLARE
   V_CLAVE NUMERIC;
BEGIN
   SELECT nextval('seq_siguiente_id') INTO V_CLAVE;
   RETURN V_CLAVE;
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**Forma en que ejecuto el script DLL**

```
import psycopg2

dll = """
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
      RETURNS numeric AS $BODY$ 
    DECLARE
       V_CLAVE NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
       SELECT nextval('seq_siguiente_id') INTO V_CLAVE;
       RETURN V_CLAVE;
    END; 
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
      OWNER TO postgres;
"""

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(dll)
```

**Error que devuelve psycopg2**

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: una cadena separada por $ está inconclusa en o cerca de «$BODY$
>   DECLARE
>      V_CLAVE NUMERIC»
>   LINE 2:   RETURNS numeric AS $BODY$
>                                ^

El script de creación funciona sin problemas ejecutandolo desde pgadmin, pero en ésta ocasión debo crearlo desde python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de muchas pruebas conseguí que funcione y de una manera muy simple. Aparentemente desde psycopg2 no reconoce el bloque **$BODY$** y por eso impide la creación de la función.

**Solución:**

En vez de usar **$BODY$** simplemente utilice **'** comilla simple como delimitador.

```
import psycopg2

dll = """
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
      RETURNS numeric AS '
    DECLARE
       V_CLAVE NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
       SELECT nextval(''seq_siguiente_id'') INTO V_CLAVE;
       RETURN V_CLAVE;
    END; '
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION fn_siguiente_id()
      OWNER TO postgres;
"""

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(dll)
```